# Api request to login/create/link user via Identity Provider

Tags: keycloak

I need to be able to do the operations that keycloak do when using identity provider: login/logout/create account/link account, via api, not via html.

I am unable to find in your documentation how can i do these actions, all the documentation is based on html and a series of redirect, by using keycloak and its theme.
This is not compatible with a single page application, or ios/android native application.

---

Examples:

1. Get token and refresh token by using Identity Provider brokering (google/facebook), for existing/already linked accounts, when i already have the google/facebook token.

Required steps:

- I get the google or facebook token, outside of keycloak.
- I need to post this token into identity provider broker.
- I need to receive from this response, the authorization and refresh tokens, just like i do a login with user/pass by using route ".../protocol/openid-connect/token"

---

2. Create a new account with the user received from Identity Provider, when i already have the google/facebook token.

Required steps:

- I get the google or facebook token, outside of keycloak.
- I need to post this token into identity provider broker.
- I receive that there is no such user, and if i want to create the user.
- I post that i want to create the new account.
- I need to receive from this response, the authorization and refresh tokens, just like i do a login with user/pass by using route ".../protocol/openid-connect/token"

---

3. Link an existing account, with the google/facebook account received by Identity Provider.

Required steps:

- I get the google or facebook token, outside of keycloak.
- I need to post this token into identity provider broker.
- I receive the information that the same account exist, and if i want to link the account.
- I post that i want to link the account.
- I need to receive from this response, the authorization and refresh tokens, just like i do a login with user/pass by using route ".../protocol/openid-connect/token"

---

I tried to do hacks and ajax calls, instead of html request, but in the end it does not resolve my problem, because i don't know what happened: it logged in? it created an account? it requires to link account?